# Auto-change TableModel based on Table view?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jtable

So I am working on a GUI that involves working with tables that can be sorted. I am noticing that when I sort a table, and I select a row from the newly sorted table, the selected row index of that row points to the data row from before the sort. I understand that this is because the view has changed, but the model has not; thus, you have the need for convertRowIndexToModel. It is also to my understanding that one can automatically update the view based on changes to the model by firing TableModelEvent's.

So here is my question: is it possible to automatically update the TableModel, based on changes to the view, so that I would not have to worry about converting the view index to table index?

Answer (score 2):

All the default table code does this automatically so you don't need to worry about this. That is if you reference the model by using the table.getValueAt(...) and table.setValueAt(...) methods then you won't have a problem.

Only code that you write that tries to access the TableModel directly will have a problem. In this case thats what the convertXXX(...) methods are for.